# Why does my nextcloud networks drive not connect with a smartcard missing error?

Tags: error-handling, windows-10, certificate, smartcard, nextcloud

I have a next-cloud server i want to access from a Windows 10 installation as a network drive. I can acess the web interface, but as soon as i try to add the network drive via the explorer- i get a error: The group policy does not allow connections without a missing smartcard.

Smartcards are not permitted and used in our network.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions; general computing questions should be asked on [SU]

Comment: Sorry, how can i migrate this question?

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to check the self-signed certificate on the next cloud instance.
Turned out there was a exepction active in the web interface, but the certificate was not integrated into the windows trusted root keystore. Once the certificate was added via  mmc.exe, the error vannished, replaced by a request for username and password.